# Identifying Logically duplicate rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables, duplicates

Here is my input table.

```
   ID   | Player1 | Player2 | Player3
  ===================================
   101  |   Tom   |  Dick   | Harry
   102  |  Jack   | Martin  | Anna
   103  |  Harry  |  Tom    | Dick
```

Here we see, for ID 101 and 103, the Players are essentially same, albeit in different order. Therefore they need to be treated as duplicate rows.

How do I somehow identify the duplicate rows, by writing a query??
Something that returns that "ID 101 and ID 103 are duplicates"??

Answer (score 3):

```
/*
CREATE  TABLE myTest
    (ID INT,
    Player1 VARCHAR(50),
    Player2 VARCHAR(50),
    Player3 VARCHAR(50));
GO

INSERT INTO myTest
VALUES
    (101, 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'),
    (102, 'Jack', 'Martin', 'Anna'),
    (103, 'Harry', 'Tom', 'Dick');
GO
*/
WITH
    Players AS (
        SELECT
            ID,
            Player1 AS Player
        FROM
            myTest
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            ID,
            Player2 AS Player
        FROM
            myTest
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            ID,
            Player3 AS Player
        FROM
            myTest),
    PlayersSorted AS (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Player) AS RowNo
        FROM
            Players)
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ID
FROM
    PlayersSorted a
JOIN
    PlayersSorted b
        ON a.ID <> b.ID
        AND a.Player = b.Player
        AND a.RowNo = b.RowNo;
```

Comment: Hi Sean,
How can the code be modified so as to identify multiple duplicates?
I mean, say if there were 8 rows. 101, 102 and 104 being duplicates.
And 105 and 108 being duplicates. Rest being unique.

and I want the output to say the three to be duplicate and the other two to be duplicate

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need?

Comment: Suppose we have

    ID   | Player1 | Player2 | Player3
   ==========================
   101  |   Tom   |  Dick    | Harry
   102  |  Jack    | Martin  | Anna
   103  |  Harry  |  Tom    | Dick
   104  |  Dick    | Tom     | Harry
   105  |  Dean  |  Zoya   |  Mark
   106  |  Anna  |  Jack    | Martin
   107  |   Lily    |  James | Patrick

Something that gives a output, 
101, 103, 104 are duplicates
and
102, 106 are duplicates

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (101, 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'),
    (102, 'Jack', 'Martin', 'Anna'),
    (103, 'Harry', 'Tom', 'Dick'),
    (104, 'Dick', 'Tom', 'Harry'),
    (105, 'Anna', 'Martin', 'Jack'),
    (106, 'Anna', 'Martin', 'Joe')
    ) T(ID, Player1, Player2, Player3)
), Numbered AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name) N
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), Player1) Player1,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), Player2) Player2,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), Player3) Player3
        FROM Src
    ) T1
    UNPIVOT
    (Name FOR Player IN (Player1, Player2, Player3)) PV
), Grouped AS
(
    SELECT N1.ID, N2.ID DuplicateID
    FROM Numbered N1
    CROSS JOIN Numbered N2
    GROUP BY N1.ID,N2.ID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN N1.N=N2.N AND N1.ID!=N2.ID AND N1.Name=N2.Name THEN 1 END)=MAX(N1.N)
)
SELECT *
FROM Grouped
WHERE ID<DuplicateID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need for each id to find minimum from 3 values

```
player1+player2+player3
player2+player3+player1
player3+player1+player2
```

The select to get the min value

```
Select sub.id, min(sub.name)
FROM (
    select
         t.id,
         CASE 
            WHEN rows.row=1 THEN t.player1+t.player2+t.player3
            WHEN rows.row=2 THEN t.player2+t.player3+t.player1
            WHEN rows.row=3 THEN t.player3+t.player1+t.player2
         END as name
    from t,
         (select 1 as row
          union
          select 2 as row
          union
          select 3 as row) rows) sub
GROUP by sub.id
```

Then you have just table like this

```
ID concat_names
1 DickHarryTom
2 AnnaJackMartin
3 DickHarryTom
```

And you can compare concat_names to find duplicates